# How can I show that linear search is faster than binary i current case?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, linear-search

I have a sorted list of elements :

```
c f g o p q r t w
```

I need to find element `f` using binary search,I did it. 
I have also found this element using linear search in 2 comparisons. 
Now I need to show that in this case linear is faster than binary,how can I do it? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Count the operations required by each algorithm. Roughly, the binary search needs:

- Compute midpoint = 5
- Compare 'p' to 'f'
- Compute midpoint = 3
- Compare 'g' to 'f'
- Compute midpoint = 2
- Compare 'f' to 'f' -- success

for roughly 6 operations.

Linear search, on the other hand, only needs:

- Compare 'c' to 'f'
- Compare 'f' to 'f' -- success

Linear search is still faster if you consider it necessary to include index computations for iterating over the list:

- i=1
- Compare 'c' to 'f'
- i=2
- Compare 'f' to 'f' -- success

Answer (score 0):

Execute both cases, and count the number of operations of each.
Binary search will be greater.

Answer (score 0):

Below I assume searched element exist in array. Binary search takes log<sub>2</sub>(N) iterations to find desired element in worst case. Average case [is close to that](http://sce.uhcl.edu/yang/teaching/csci3333spring2011/Average%20case%20analysis%20of%20binary%20search.pdf). Linear search takes N/2 iterations in average to find element.

Iteration is binary search usually consists of 3-4 steps: calculate mid index, take mid element and up to two comparisons. So in average searching using binary search will take log<sub>2</sub>(N) * 3.5 steps.

In linear search it requires two operations — getting element value at current index and comparison. 
In average linear search will take N * 2 / 2 = N steps.

In your case we have log<sub>2</sub>(9) * 3.5 = 3.1 * 3.5 = 10.85 steps for binary search.
And 9 steps for linear search.

So, on 9-sized array linear search seems to be slightly faster in average, but not very much. On bigger arrays binary search will easily outperform linear search.